# Node JS Sequelize many-to-many relationship throwing error column id does not exist

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am building a Node JS web application. I am using Sequelize, https://sequelize.org/ for manipulating the database logic. Now, I am having a problem with bulk insert and many-to-many relationships.

I have a model called, Region with the following code.

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Region extends Model {
   
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      Region.belongsToMany(models.ExchangeRequest, {
        through: 'RegionExchangeRequests',
        as: 'exchangeRequests',
        foreignKey: "region_id",
        otherKey: "exchange_request_id"
      })
    }
  };
  Region.init({
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    latitude: DataTypes.FLOAT,
    longitude: DataTypes.FLOAT
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Region',
  });
  return Region;
};
```

Then, I have a model called, ExchangeRequest with the following code.

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class ExchangeRequest extends Model {

    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      ExchangeRequest.belongsToMany(models.Region, {
        through: 'RegionExchangeRequests',
        as: 'regions',
        foreignKey: 'exchange_request_id',
        otherKey: "region_id"
      })

      ExchangeRequest.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'userId', as: 'user', onDelete: 'cascade' });
    }
  };
  ExchangeRequest.init({
    exchange_rate: DataTypes.DECIMAL,
    currency: DataTypes.STRING,
    amount: DataTypes.DECIMAL,
    buy_or_sell: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    note: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    phone: DataTypes.STRING,
    address: DataTypes.STRING,
    userId: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'ExchangeRequest',
  });
  return ExchangeRequest;
};
```

Then I have the RegionExchangeRequest with the following code.

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class RegionExchangeRequest extends Model {

    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  };
  RegionExchangeRequest.init({
    region_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    exchange_request_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'RegionExchangeRequest',
  });
  return RegionExchangeRequest;
};
```

I have a function that is doing the bulk insert on RegionExchangeReques as follow.

```
const create = async ({
  exchange_rate,
  currency,
  amount,
  buy_or_sell,
  note,
  email,
  phone,
  address,
  region_ids,
  userId
}) => {
  try {
    let exchangeRequest = await ExchangeRequest.create({
      exchange_rate,
      currency,
      amount,
      buy_or_sell,
      note,
      email,
      phone,
      address,
      userId
    });

    if (region_ids && region_ids.length > 0) {
      let pivotData = [ ];
      region_ids.forEach(regionId => {
          pivotData.push({
            exchange_request_id: exchangeRequest.id,
            region_id: regionId
          })
      })
      let regionExchangeRequests = await RegionExchangeRequest.bulkCreate(pivotData);
    }

    return {
      error: false,
      data: exchangeRequest
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return {
      error: true,
      code: 500,
      message: e.message
    }
  }
}
```

When the function is called, it is throwing the following error.

```
"column \"id\" of relation \"RegionExchangeRequests\" does not exist"
```

The following line is throwing the error.

```
let regionExchangeRequests = await RegionExchangeRequest.bulkCreate(pivotData);
```

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In many-to-many relationship you specified RegionExchangeRequests as through table that connects two other tables, and in sequelize you cannot call usual model methods in through table.To do so you need to create super many-to-many relationship, for more information check out this link [advanced-associations-in-sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html)